# Hochschild homology of stable categories as topological chiral homology

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, noncommutative-geometry, hochschild-homology

Sorry for [repost](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4634623/hochschild-homology-of-stable-categories-as-topological-chiral-homology) from Math Stack Exchange:

Let $\mathscr{C}_0$ be a small idempotent complete stable category tensored over some symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{E}$.
Its Ind-completion $\mathscr{C} := \operatorname{Ind}(\mathscr{C}_0)$ is a dualizable object in $Pr_L^{st}$, the (very large) category of presentable categories with morphisms given by left adjoints.
More precisely, the Hom-pairing provides a unit and a counit
$$\eta: \operatorname{Ind}(\mathcal{E}) \rightarrow \mathscr{C}\otimes \mathscr{C}^\vee \ \text{and} \ \epsilon: \mathscr{C}^\vee \otimes \mathscr{C} \rightarrow \operatorname{Ind}(\mathcal{E})$$
satisfying the standard triangle identity which exhibit $\mathscr{C}^\vee = \operatorname{Ind}(\mathscr{C}_0^{op})$  as its dual.
Hoyois, Scherotzke, and Sibilla show in Proposition 4.24 of their [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03589) that the composition $\epsilon \circ \eta$ generalizes Hochschild homology.

There is another generalization by topological chiral homology in, for example, Section 5.5 of Lurie's [HA](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf). However, he only does it for algebras instead of categories. My question is if generalization to categories has been done and if there is any reference? If not, what is, in principle, the modifications needed in order to define such a theory?

Edit for easy reference: As pointed out by Adrien in the comment, this is explained in example 4.2.2 of Lurie's [cobordism hypothesis paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0465).

Comment: If I understand what you're asking I suppose you're looking for the cobordism hypothesis (https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0465) aka beta version of factorization (=topological chiral) homology https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.04007. This takes as input a sufficiently dualizable $n$-category and an $k$-dimensional manifold $M$ and produces a $n-k$-category. If your $n$-category is $A$-mod for an $E_n$-algebra $A$, this is topological chiral homology. If $n=1$ and $M$ is a circle this produces the trace/dimension of the dualizable category $A$-mod, ie HH(A).

Comment: Thanks for the references. I will check them later. Just to clarify what I mean, which is probably much simpler, let $A$ be an $E_1$-algebra, then there is an identification between chain complexes $A^{fact}(S^1) = HH_*(A)$ as in theorem 4.2.1 of in Factorization Algebras in Quantum Field Theory I by Costello and Gwilliam. Now for a stable $1$-category $\mathscr{C}$, use $HH_*(\mathscr{C})$ to denote the composition $\epsilon \circ \eta$, my question is if there is a natural object $C$ built out of $\mathscr{C}$ such that $C^{fact}(S^1) = HH_*(\mathscr{C})$ in some sense?

Comment: Let me also mention that one family of categories I am interested is given by coherent sheaves $\operatorname{Coh}(X)$ on some derived scheme $X$. Using the description as composition of unit and counit, which can be realized geometrically by push-pull functoriality, gives the HKR theorem using [arxiv.org/pdf/1002.3636.pdf](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.3636.pdf). I'm wondering if this can be seen from the factorization homology point of view as well.

Comment: I guess that was my point, but I might be misunderstanding your question: to a dualizable category $\mathcal C$ one associate a 1d TFT which I claim you can think of as a version of factorization homology with coefficients in $\mathcal C$, whose evaluation on a circle gives $HH_*(\mathcal C)$, and via excision this boils down to the definition you gave as composition of coevaluation and evaluation. So I'd say what you're describing is already "seeing it from factorization homology",

Comment: I see. I don't know TQFT enough to notice that. (As I mentioned, this is really a math stack exchange question.) Maybe what I am asking with really the elaboration (or reference of it) of what you just say: What is the 1d TFT one can associate to a dualizable category and how I can think it as a factorization homology (and thus recover the unit/counit description)?

Comment: You can look at section 4.2 (especially example 4.2.2) of the first paper I mentioned (the one by Lurie) where this is spelled out. Basically, a dualizable object $X$ determines a 1d TFT whose value on a point is $X$. Its value on a circle can be computed by breaking the circle into two pieces, which gives the formula for the "dimension" of $X$ as the composition of coevaluation followed by evaluation as you said. Now, quite generally, factorization homology is essentially a sort of TFT which is especially easy to compute.(continued)

Comment: In this low dimensional example, this boils down to the fact that for an algebra $A$, $A-mod$ is automatically dualizable as a category, and that the dimension of that category coincides with $\int_{S^1} A$. Indeed computing this either from the perspective above, or using excision for factorization directly gives the same answer $A \otimes_{A \otimes A^{op}} A$, basically because ev/coev of $A-mod$ are both given by tensoring with $A$ seen as a bimodule in various ways.